# Implementing a custom SortedMap in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

Somehow, I can't seem to correctly implement a SortedMap. Here's a minimal (non-)working example:

```
class MyMap[A](t: Map[Long, A]) extends SortedMap[Long, A]  {
  protected val internalMap = TreeMap(t.toArray: _*)

  def -(key: Long) = MyMap(internalMap - key)
  def get(key: Long) = internalMap.get(key)
  def rangeImpl(from: Option[Long], until: Option[Long]) = TreeMap(internalMap.rangeImpl(from, until))
  def iterator = internalMap.iterator
  def ordering = internalMap.ordering
}
```

But, whatever I pass into the `MyMap` constructor, calling, for example, its `size`, always returns 0.

---

**Addendum:** I just copy-pasted the code to a new project, and it worked 8-\ Anyway, let me change the question in order to make it useful: is this the correct way to extend `SortedMap`?

Comment: To answer your addendum with a question: Since `TreeMap` implements `SortedMap`, why do you need to wrap it in `MyMap`? Why not just use a `TreeMap` directly?

(Just to confirm: We are talking about `scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap`, right?)

Comment: @Chris: That was a minimal working example :-) In real-life, I want to re-implement my own functions for a different kind of SortedMap.

Comment: And yes, we are talking about `scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding a couple of missing methods to make it compile, your code worked fine for me:

```
class MyMap[A](t: Map[Long, A]) extends SortedMap[Long, A]  {
  protected val internalMap = TreeMap(t.toArray: _*)
  def +[B1 >: A](kv: (Long, B1)) = new MyMap(internalMap + kv)
  def -(key: Long) = new MyMap(internalMap - key)
  def get(key: Long) = internalMap.get(key)
  def rangeImpl(from: Option[Long], until: Option[Long]) = internalMap.rangeImpl(from, until)
  def iterator = internalMap.iterator
  def ordering = internalMap.ordering
}
```

From the REPL:

```
scala> t
res5: Map[Long,String] = Map(123 -> abc, 456 -> def)

scala> new MyMap(t)
res6: MyMap[String] = Map(123 -> abc, 456 -> def)

scala> res6.size
res7: Int = 2
```

Am I missing something?